# how to save vector of vector of type enum in

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, enums, stdvector

I have a vector of a vector where it represents my map after loading from a file, there is a problem, how can I save into it? Like at coordinate x and y is this type ?

```
//Field.cpp
enum Fieldtype <River,Building,Earth,Sky...>

//Logic.cpp
std::vector<std::vector<Field::Fieldtype>> my_map;
char array[10][10];
```

After loading my map from a txt file into a char array, now is the problem how can I save it into map?

for examle this map:

```
SSSSS
SSSSS
BBBBB
EEEEE
```

where S is my sky, B is building... I tried with

```
for(int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
{
   for(int y= 0; y< 6; y++)
   {
      if(array[x][y] == 'S')
         my_map.at(x).at(y) = Field::Sky;
   }

}
```

this gets me a vector out of range. Can somone help me?

Comment: Consider using `std::map<std::pair<int,int>, FieldType> my_map;` instead of vector.  Then it simply becomes `my_map.insert({x,y}, Field::Sky);`

Comment: Have a loop that assembles each line using `push_back` into a local vector and then at the end of each line calls `push_back` to add that local vector to the `my_map` vector.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie do you know how to innitialize the map in constructor? Like this? 
 Logic() : board_width_(0),
                   board_height_(0),
                   map_(0,0) {} it gives me an error somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What's the problem ?**

The problem is that when you have created the vector with:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Field::Fieldtype>> my_map;
```

this vector is completely empty when you try to load it.  So any attempt to access to an element, even `my_map[0][0]`, will be out of range !

**How to solve it ?**

You should populate the vector using either `resize()` or `push_back()` or a combination of both, for example:

```
my_map.resize(6);     // takes care of all the x at once 
for(int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
{
   for(int y= 0; y< 6; y++)
   {
      if(array[x][y] == 'S')
         my_map[x].push_back(Field::Sky);   // add the y one by one 
      ...
   }
}
```

**Further improvements**

To avoid a lot of `if` clauses to process the different letters, you could also create a map:

```
map<char, Field::Fieldtype> mapfield;
```

You would populate your map with:

```
mapfield['S'] = Field::Fieldtype::Sky;
...
```

Then you could rewrite your loop:

```
my_map.resize(5);     // takes care of all the x at once 
for(int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
   for(int y= 0; y< 6; y++)
      my_map[x].push_back(mapfield[array[x][y]]);
```

A simpler but more dirty alternative would be to define :

```
enum Fieldtype:char {River='R',Building='B',Earth='E',Sky='S', ...};
```

and in the loop populate the fields with:

```
my_map[x].push_back(static_cast<Fieldtype>(array[x][y]));
```